# Whitening transformation does NOT return a unit covariance matrix

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, svd

For this question, I am using the following [Wiki definition of Matrix whitening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation):

[image]

From the definition, I expect the covariance matrix of `Y` to be the identity matrix. However, this is far from the truth!

Here is the reproduction:

```
import numpy as np
# random matrix
dim1 = 512 # dimentionality_of_features
dim2 = 100 # no_of_samples

X = np.random.rand(dim1, dim2)
# centering to have mean 0
X = X - np.mean(X, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# covariance of X
Xcov = np.dot(X, X.T) / (X.shape[1] - 1)

# SVD decomposition
# Eigenvecors and eigenvalues
Ec, wc, _ = np.linalg.svd(Xcov)
# get only the first positive ones (for numerical stability)
k_c = (wc > 1e-5).sum()
# Diagonal Matrix of eigenvalues
Dc = np.diag((wc[:k_c]+1e-6)**-0.5)
# E D ET should be the whitening matrix
W = Ec[:,:k_c].dot(Dc).dot(Ec[:,:k_c].T)

# SVD decomposition End




Y = W.dot(X)
# Now apply the same to the whitened X
Ycov = np.dot(Y, Y.T) / (Y.shape[1] - 1)
print(Ycov)

>> [[ 0.19935189 -0.00740203 -0.00152036 ...  0.00133161 -0.03035149
      0.02638468]  ...
```

It seems that it won't give me a unit diagonal matrix, unless, `dim2 >> dim1`.

If I take `dim2=1` then I get a vector (although in the example I get an error due to division by 0), and by the Wikis definition, it is incorrect?

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Asked https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/whitening-transformation-does-not-return-a-unit-covariance-matrix